# How to attach sandbox Apple ID to device to test in-app purchases if device has not been used for testing purchases before?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In order to test in-app purchases in your iOS app you have to create new Apple ID and attach it explicitly to device (sandbox Apple Id, `Settings/iTunes & App Store/Sandbox Account`), but I noticed, that on latest iPhones there is no such option and it appear in settings only after the first time you use the device to attempt a purchase if you make first purchase using your main Apple ID as sandbox.

What should I do if I do not have opportunity to make this first test purchase from device using my real Apple ID? is there any workaround?